# Hibernation in ectotherm and endotherm

Tags: homework, homeostasis

> Both snake and weasel hibernate. Which of the following is correct?
>
> A. They will die when temperature decreases below the critical
>   temperature.
>
> B. Weasel will die when temperature decreases below the critical
>   temperature.
>
> C. Snake will die and weasel will wake up when the temperature
>   decreases below the critical temperature.
>
> D. Weasel keeps low body temperature and slow heart rate during the
>   entire period of hibernation.

I don't think any of them should die, they would have some adaptation to prevent that. So,is the answer (D) ?

What is the snake's adaptation in this situation ?

Comment: A relevant [article](http://www.une.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/31004/2011-geiser-hibernation-endotherms.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weasels don't hibernate.  See http://icwdm.org/handbook/carnivor/Weasels.asp

Both will die when the temperature falls below a certain level.  The difference between snakes (ectotherms) and weasels (endotherms) is that the snake's body temperature will fluctuate more, depending on the surrounding temperature.